# How do I close the editor in iPhoto?

Tags: photos.app

In iPhoto 09, how do you close the editor without closing the Event you're working in?

For example, you can enlarge a photo with <kbd>space</kbd>, then go back to the event with <kbd>space</kbd> again (single-clicking the image also goes back). However, if I'm editing the image, clicking "Done", double-clicking the image, and pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> all take me back to "All Events". How do you close the editor only, so you can go back to the thumbnail view of the event, or at least to the enlarged photo view?

Answer (score 1):

Since I got different results from @Brandon, I started experimenting again. <kbd>Esc</kbd>, Done, and others behave as expected when I follow these steps:

1. Select Events from the Library group on the sidebar
2. Select your event
3. Edit a photo
4. Click done, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or any other quit-editing combination.
5. Voila, you're back at the event's thumbnail view.

If, however, you do as I've been doing while doing one-off imports of additional photos and merging them in to your existing event, you'll be in this situation:

1. *Do work...*
2. Select your event from the Recent group on the sidebar (first item under Recent, above "Last 12 months").
3. Edit a photo
4. Click done, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or any other quit-editing combination.
5. You're kicked back to the All events view, even though the sidebar shows your recent event is still selected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will but I put some pictures into iPhoto 09 and messed around with it to see if I could get it to what it looks like you trying to do. I pressed fn + esc. & it looks like it saves all edits and also brings you back to just that photo. Does this help?

Comment: I tried this, and it also exited to the all events view.